# Python Yahoo-Finance Try-Except with Continue for Problem Tickers in a List

Tags: python, yahoo-finance, try-except

I am trying to pull the closing stock prices for certain dates from yahoo finance using python DataReader. I have a list of stocks symbols that contain some problem symbols as well that may not be recognized by yahoo finance. So I am using try-except with continue statement to ignore the problematic ticker.
The aim is to save the data into Data Frame and in CSV.
The problem is I only get last symbol data without its name.

```
a_list = ['WTC.AX', 'WOW.AX','AAB.TO','XXX.XO','ABT.TO','QCD.TO' ]
```

for code in a_list:

```
    try:
        data = wb.get_data_yahoo(code,start, end) 
        Close_prices= data['Close']       

    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
        continue
    finally:
        Close_prices
```

Output :

> No data fetched for symbol XXX.XO using YahooDailyReader

```
print(data)

print(Close_prices)
```

I expected to see results similar to  :

```
Date     2018-06-29

Symbols 

AAB.TO     0.130000

AAV.TO     4.110000

ABT.TO     6.930000

AC.TO     21.250000

ACD.TO     9.180000
```

But what I get is either :

```
                High        Low       Open      Close  Volume  Adj Close
Date                                                                     
2018-06-29  26.530001  26.530001  26.530001  26.530001       0  26.018112
```

or this :

```
Date
2018-06-29    26.530001
Name: Close, dtype: float64
```

Only the last price data with no stock ticker/symbols.

Thanks in Advance.